# Is it possible to mirror a private Maven S3 repository with Nexus?

Tags: java, maven, amazon-s3, maven-plugin, sonatype

I'm trying to use S3 to deploy our artifacts (so I don't need a server running), while keeping a local Nexus server to 3rd parties JARs and browse everything easier.

So far I found that I can use [Spring AWS Wagon](https://github.com/spring-projects/aws-maven) to publish to S3, but I could't find a way to make Nexus read a S3 repository.

Is it possible? How can I inform Nexus which credentials to use?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to achieve this?

Comment: @whitfin yes I did. Actually using Spring AWS Wagon is enough. You can declare a S3 repository and maven will look to it normally.

Answer (score 0):

Treat the S3 repository as any other maven repository and create a "Proxy Repository" that points to it. I would then create a virtual repository that looks at both your local repo and the s3 repo.

Comment: And how would Nexus authenticate in S3?